# is PyODict_New supported by Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-c-api

I can't find it a Python documentation, although it exist at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/odictobject.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you refer to is a C implementation of the `OrderedDict` class. But if you are programming in Python, not C, all you need to do is import the Python implementation from the `collections` library module:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
mydict = OrderedDict()
```

I'm a little puzzled that you would want to use the C implementation in a Python program.

And, in any case, from Python 3.6, normal `dict`s in Python also preserve input order, which means there is now little reason to use an `OrderedDict` in new code. Raymond Hettinger (who wrote the `OrderedDict` class) [tweeted](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/773978885092323328) in September 2016 "OrderedDict is dead. Long live dicts that are ordered."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I wanted to pass ordered dictionary from C to Python, so the end of your answer shows it's already embedded at the regular Dict, and that explains why I couldn't find it at Python documentation.